# Perl - Lowercase Accent Letters

Tags: perl

Using Perl, i'm trying to lowercase words with accents and special chars with `lc()` but i can't.

For example:

> É UM MAÇO

returns

> É um maÇo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
-bash$ perl -we 'use utf8; binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; print lc "É UM MAÇO"'
é um maço
```

`utf8` indicates your program text is unicode. `binmode` ensures proper output of wide characters.

You can also `use Encode;`, see the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html).

Comment: The `-CSA` flag will tell Perl that both std{in,out,err} and the arguments from `@ARGV` (but not their file contents unless you add `D` to `-CSAD`) are in UTF-8, but you do still need the `use utf8` internally.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
use locale;
```

into your script. It should make various functions including `lc` work with accents. Full testing script:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use locale;
use utf8;

print lc('É UM MAÇO');    # gives "é um maço"
```

Comment: @tchrist - can you please elaborate? I know that locale support varies, but it worked well for my czech text manipulation on Windows machines.

Comment: locales are a very old-fashioned and restricted **pre-Unicode** way of dealing with text. They are terribly unportable, very buggy, and they do not work at all with anything except legacy 8-bit data — and then only sometimes. The right thing to do is to set the encoding layer so that your legacy stuff gets translated into Unicode, then rely on (tailorable) Unicode rules for case mapping and collation. That is infinitely more portable.

Comment: @tchrist - thanks for follow-up and explanation. I assumed that locales are complement to unicode, but obviously was wrong. Will look deeper in unicode area.

Comment: It is usually a really bad idea to mix locales with Unicode, at least for LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html and made sure you have all your settings set up correctly. Also would be good to post minimal code to reproduce the effect.